# How to assemble bytes from a bit stream?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make bytes out of a source of individual bits /booleans in the Java language.  I'd like the routine to run as quickly as possible, and I'm after the unsigned flavour of byte.  I've done some internet searches, but can't actually find any code specifically for this.

All I can come up with is the following, which seems amateurish.  I'm aware of the BitSet, but those are internally represented as Longs (I'm using a 32 bit machine so double handling) and it has a huge API so I expect it to be slow.  Can there be anything more efficient, perhaps at low level?

```
public int nextByte() {
    int b = 0;


    for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        if (nextBoolean()) {
            b++;
        }


        b = b << 1;
    }


    if (nextBoolean()) {
        b++;
    }


    return b;
}
```

Comment: re "expect it to be slow": Advice #1 to programmers: Don't pre-optimize everything. Most of the time, it is unnecessary

Comment: Where do you actually get a "bit stream" from?

Comment: Just like @markspace said. If you can show us how you are accessing a "bit stream" in Java then we may be able to help guide you.

Comment: @markspace It's probably poor semantics on my behalf, but nextBoolean() just returns  random bits from another routine.  This is unavoidable.   It's not accessing a "Stream" in the strict Java API sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as efficient as it can be:

```
public int nextByte() {
    int b = nextBoolean() ? 0x80 : 0;

    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x40;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x20;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x10;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x08;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x04;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x02;
    if (nextBoolean()) b = b | 0x01;

    return b;
}
```

If you wish to try really, really hard, you may use:

```
public int nextByte() {
    return
        (nextBoolean() ? 0x80 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x40 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x20 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x10 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x08 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x04 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x02 : 0)
        | (nextBoolean() ? 0x01 : 0);
}
```

If this were C language, this last solution would *not* be guaranteed to work, as the C standard says calls to `nextBoolean()` may occur in any order the compiler sees fit. However, [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/), section [15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), guarantees (apparent) strict left-to-right evaluation, so in Java bits *are* guaranteed to go in the correct order. On the other hand, the next sentence explicitly recommends code to "not rely crucially on this specification" and that "code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect". Of course, calling `nextBoolean()` is a textbook example of "a side effect", and doing it 8 times in a single expression goes against the recommendation.

Furthermore (and most importantly, and in line with other answers), I say the most computationally expensive part of these solutions (or yours, for that matter) is probably the eight calls to `nextBoolean()` and not the loop or the conditionals, so I don't think you can get this going visibly faster without avoiding those calls.

Comment: Note that you could also use expressions like `1 << 2`, `1 << 3`, `1 << 4` instead of the hex values. The compiler would eliminate the shift operation anyway.

Comment: @jojonete  Just tried this, and as you suspected, it made no difference.  Both your and mine implementations ran at 2.9 million bytes /sec.  Your's seems neater though.